# How to include custom content folder for choosing renderings

Tags: presentation

In the presentation details, while adding a rendering, it shows these two nodes.

[image]

Is it possible to add my custom folder to show up in that dialog, which also has renderings.
The folder will be under content - `/sitecore/content/MyCustomRenderings`

This is for a POC I'm trying to do, where the dev or author can create a rendering in the content tree.

Comment: Sitecore stores Renderings only in sitecore/Layout/Renderings folders. You can create a folder here for any custom renderings. Ideally your renderings shall be created inside either of Foundation, Feature or Project folder in sitecore/Layout/Renderings. Once you create your rendering inside such folders, your rendering will also start appearing in Select Rendering dialog for selection. If you want only your custom renderings to appear in Select Rendering dialog, you can make use of Allowed Controls option on placeholder settings.

Comment: If you still want your folder to appear in the dialog, try overriding its code behind in - Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Dialogs.SelectRendering